# How to export or backup column formatting JSON values?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, json-formatting, column-formatting

Is there a way to export or backup the column formatting JSON that has been applied to SharePoint list columns?

Obviously, column formatting is so useful that it is often applied to lots of lists, and in dynamic environments the values change often.

Apart from manually copying and pasting the JSON values for each column in each list into a JSON file, is there a way to export or backup column formatting JSON values?

Comment: Are you trying to export the JSON itself?

Comment: My understanding is that column formatting for each column is contained in one JSON object with multiple properties.  (Similarly, each customised `Layout` view is a JSON object).  So if I have a SharePoint list, and 5 columns have column formatting, there would be 5 JSON objects.  (If I also modified `Gallery` view, there would be another JSON object).  So any method that simplifies retrieving all JSON objects associated with a list (eg as an 'export' or 'backup') would be great.  As long as it is clear which JSON is associated with which List, Column, View etc, I think any method is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the JSON code applied to column formatting using PnP PowerShell like:

```
$field = Get-PnPField -List "JSONFormatting" -Identity "Status" -Includes Title,CustomFormatter
$field.CustomFormatter
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

You can also get the JSON using SharePoint REST API like:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('JSONFormatting')/fields?$select=Title,CustomFormatter
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

**For list views**: Use below endpoint:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('JSONFormatting')/views/getbytitle('All Items')?$select=Title,CustomFormatter
```

You can change the view name as per your requirements.

Comment: I'm sure this answer will be very helpful to someone (and me in another environment), but in locked down corporate environment, is there way to do this without PnP PowerShell?  I am Owner of Microsoft Teams teams and SharePoint sites, but that is as far as my permissions go.  When I tried to use `Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com"`, I got `Connect-PnPOnline : ********: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '****-****-****-****-****' named 'PnP Management Shell'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.`

Comment: Will you able to use [SharePointOnlinePowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online)?

Comment: It seems to also require admin level account to run anything, I installed with `Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -Scope CurrentUser` and it seemed to install but I cannot connect with anything like `Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential user@contoso.com`

Comment: If you are able to use SharePoint REST API, check my updated answer.

Comment: This is very helpful and thorough answer, so am making it accepted solution, however to access REST API involves more permissions than I have (and a registered app in Azure)...`ACTUALLY` I just tried suggestion in *browser* and it returned the XML:  `https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('My%20List')/fields?$select=Title,CustomFormatter`.  The containing tags are `<d:CustomFormatter>` (which contains the JSON) and `<d:Title>` (which displays name of the column).  Thanks!  The only thing is that the custom `Gallery` `View` JSON does not seem to be in there.

Comment: Yes, because the REST endpoint `/fields` is for the columns in SharePoint list & not for list views. Check updated answer for list views endpoint

Answer (score 1):

you can try this tool that allows you to export SharePoint lists to JSON, XML, Collections Power Apps and more.

https://export-list-sharepoint.web.app/
[image]